# Regex - Ignore if group has prefix

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, regex-look-ahead

I am trying to capture 8 digit phone numbers in free text. This should be ignored if a particular string appears before.

My regex:

```
(\b(\+?001|002)?[-]?\d{4}(-|\s)?\d{4}\b)
```

To Capture:

```
+001 12345678
12345678
```

Not Capture:

```
TTT-12345678-123
TTT-12345678
```

I am trying to use negative look behind as below example:

```
\w*(?<!foo)bar
```

But the above works only if the regex doesn't have subsequent groups.

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)(?:\+?001|002)?[-\s]?\d{4}[-\s]?\d{4}(?!\S)`

Comment: This will capture the last 8 digits in a 10 digit number also. eg:  >1234567896

Comment: No, it won't, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WyvDZY/2).

Comment: -12345678-, <12345678> will not be captured. @WiktorStribiżew: Actually i dont want to capture 8 digit numbers only after this specific string "TTT". But no:12345678 should still be captured

Comment: Got it, try `(?<!TTT-)(?<!\w)(?:\+?001|002)?[-\s]?\d{4}[-\s]?\d{4}\b`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WyvDZY/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!TTT-)(?<!\w)(?:\+?001|002)?[-\s]?\d{4}[-\s]?\d{4}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WyvDZY/3)

**Details**

- `(?<!TTT-)` - no `TTT-` allowed immediately on the left
- `(?<!\w)` - no word char allowed immediately on the left
- `(?:\+?001|002)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `+001`, `001` or `002`
- `[-\s]?` - an optional `-` or whitespace
- `\d{4}` - any four digits
- `[-\s]?\d{4}` -  - an optional `-` or whitespace and any four digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

If the number can be glued to a word char on the right, replace the `\b` word boundary with the right-hand digit boundary, `(?!\d)`.